# Centos: creating new ADS samba share

Tags: centos, active-directory, samba

I followed several guides to set up samba sharing on our domain. I've got it working where I can join the domain, list the shares, and connect to the samba share from windows. When I connect from windows, I am dumped into the user home directory and can read/write.

I'm trying now to create a new separate share on Samba to use via windows. I created the folder, added it to smb.conf, but can not access the share from windows no matter what. smb.log has zero info nor messages or any log under /var/log/samba. When I try to connect to the new share from windows in Explorer, I am prompted for username password and upon entering am just met with the un/pw prompt again. Via cmd net use, I get an error stating the password is invalid: "The password is invalid for domain/user".

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = MYDOMAIN
netbios name = samba
server string = Samba Server 3.0
security = ads
realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
password server = 192.168.1.11
encrypt passwords = yes
printcap name = /etc/printcap
load printers = no
printing = cups
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
max log size = 0
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
local master = no
domain master = no
preferred master = no
dns proxy = no
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
writable = yes
valid users = %S
create mode = 0664
directory mode = 0775
[printers]
comment = All Printers
path = /var/spool/samba
browseable = no
guest ok = no
writable = no
printable = yes 

[newShare] 
comment = NewShare Share 
path = /home/share/newShare/ 
valid users = @"MYDOMAIN.LOCAL\Domain Users"
public = no 
writable = yes 
printable = no 
create mask = 0765
```

It's likely I don't have permissions set right on the directory I created; ownership is root:root and 0755, but I didn't see any good examples of how it should be in the millions of tutorials I looked through. However, I'm not sure that would cause the invalid password error.

smb.log:

```
[2012/01/13 11:06:42, 0] smbd/server.c:main(958)
  smbd version 3.0.33-3.29.el5_7.4 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2008
[2012/01/13 11:14:22, 0] smbd/server.c:main(958)
  smbd version 3.0.33-3.29.el5_7.4 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2008
[2012/01/13 11:29:26, 0] smbd/server.c:main(958)
  smbd version 3.0.33-3.29.el5_7.4 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2008
```

[not helpful]

I'm not sure at this point where to try and look for the problem.

Oh, I also messed with selinux stuff as a result of find here on SF. It didn't break anything, but it didn't fix anything either. [chcon and semanage fcontext stuff]

Comment: You sure that `getent group` returns `MYDOMAIN.LOCAL\Domain Users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tinkering, I was able to get it to work. I'm not sure the exact constellation of changes that got things working, but I think it was at least in part due to upgrading samba to 3.4.

Some things:

make sure clocks are in sync;

`allowed users = @"DOMAIN+Domain Users"`

setting WINS helped; name resolution is important

`log level = 2`

OH! and after upgrading samba, `winbindd` seemed to have disappeared... needed to reinstall